# Can someone translate this "hidden" message from Hebrew to English?

Tags: hebrew

Can someone translate this "hidden" message? I would have pulled out the letters, but it is difficult for me not being very familiar with Hebrew to even identify some of the letters.

This is a picture of a tree stump with a green shoot coming out of the roots and I'm interested to know if this has to do with Isaiah 11.

This is from the back cover of a new book called Preserving the Restoration by Denver C. Snuffer Jr.

I also find it strange that there is what appears to be a pine cone at the stump. The rest of the cover art depicts an olive vineyard and olive trees which, I'm pretty sure, are not coniferous.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site Micah. We generally discourage questions about the Hebrew language except as they relate to Judasim.

Comment: I think that this is off topic because it is focused just on the Hebrew but if a Jewish context can be established for this (where is the picture from?) and the question edited to ask about the Jewish content of the message, it might be on topic.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I just tried to bring the question more closely to being about Judaism, and not just about the Hebrew language. Let me know if the edits are sufficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is from Isaiah 11:1

1.And a shoot shall spring forth from the stem of Jesse, and a twig shall sprout from his roots.

א.וְיָצָא חֹטֶר מִגֶּזַע יִשָׁי וְנֵצֶר מִשָּׁרָשָׁיו יִפְרֶה